# PHP: How to add variables and quotes to a variable

Tags: php

How can I add  variables and quotes to a variable?

in the output it just prints the variables 
This is the code I have tried

```
 $pl2 = '{"comment":"' . $nmp3 . '","file":"' . $pmp3 . '"},';
```

Comment: What is the exact value you want this variable to be set to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with:

```
$pl2 = json_encode(array(
    'comment' => $nmp3,
    'file' => $pmp3
));
```

Comment: You are mixing javascript syntax in there... it should be `=>` and not `:` =p

Comment: That worked. thanks. but why it's changed variable value(which is a path) to \/users\/crazy_bash\/online\/test\/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work:

```
$p = ' {"comment": ' . $nmp3; 
$p = $p.' "," file " : " ' . $pmp3; 
$p=$p.' "}," ';
echo $p;
```